# Automatic downloading of files from website

Tags: java, html, web-scraping

I have a website that has a lot of direct download links. It is a hyperlink titled "Download". In order to download the file, I need to right click on it and press "Save link as" and it asks for a location. How do I make this process automatic. I mean, fetch all the links named "Download" and do the right click and save as operation. Using IDM (Internet Download Manager), it simplifies to just a click on the "Download" hyperlink. But, I have to click on each link. There are around 750 such links. Is there a way to make this process automatic?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a Java question? Could you possibly meant to have tagged it for JavaScript? The two are very different.

Comment: I am not sure about what to use. I tagged Java because I saw some websites that used to java to extract links using Java. But, it didn't have a name specification. The website I talked about also has 750 links named Explore and View. I just need the ones that say "Download". I hope this clears up the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on u r description i understood that, u need to download the files from some site that u own.

If you own the site. u can login into you hosting panel. Your website developer might have placed a folder for all the files. just use any ftp client link filezilla or some thing else and using u r ftp credentials login and download all files in that folder.

if you want to clone every thing in u r hosting or a site use CuteFTP ftp client software. After you login into u site. go to menu and clone u r directory.

If you don't own the site or if you donot have ur credentials.

Here are the other options.

There are many ways u can solve this issue.

Download firefox.

Go to extensions and download the extension
Download them all extension at this link

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/

after installing this addon.
follow the tutorial by the author. U r all set. 
Make sure to use filters to download specific file types.

and using Free Download Manager,

select all the area by click and drag action. After selecting right click on the selected area and click on download selected with FDM. This  should do the trick.

I am not sure if you this option with u r IDM.

Cheers. Let me know if this worked or not.

Comment: I also found the dTA extension and it works. I set the download to be automatic. Thanks for the answer anyway!